# overflow: hidden on a cell -- unexpected result

Tags: html, overflow

A newbie to web development -- have to restrict the size of a cell(`display:table-cell`) ,hence using `overflow:hidden`

if the cell contents are more than the width of the cell (i want it to be hidden) the content is not getting hidden even with `overflow:hidden`

Here's a gist of the code

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
.table{
display: table;
}
.row{
display: table-row;
} 
.cell{
display: table-cell;
}
.mod{
width: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<div class="table">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
   Foo
  </div>
  <div class="cell mod">
   barbarbarbarbarbar
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</html>
```

And if the width(in class mod) is replaced with max-width -- it seems to work.Confused on how its working with `max-width` but not with `width`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for overflow:hidden to work the element must be floated. If you set float:left; in your .mod class it will hide the rest of the text that doesn't fit in the cell.

Note that you should float your other classes aswell so you don't encounter problems later.

Comment: Vivek is using `overflow:hidden` to hide overflowing content, not as a clear-fix.